# To find the xpath of dropdown list of languages in Google sign in

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testing, xpath

[Dropdown button of Signin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL861.png)

On clicking the dropdown button , languages are displayed . I want to store all these languages in a list and then iterate using the for loop so that I can select one.

I tried so many ways to create dynamic xpath but it returns me "0" when I check for the size of the list.

Here is the code

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fhl%3Den-US&hl=en&gmb=exp&biz=false&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp");
        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'‪English (United States)‬')]"))
      .click();
        
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@jsname='V68bde']//div"));        
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the issue is with list selector: `//div[@jsname='V68bde']//div`
You need to refer the element that actually contains text: `//div[@jsname='V68bde']//div//span`